# Using Predicates as Key in Dictionary, Getting Error When Trying To Call Value

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I was experimenting with turning a simple if-else chain into something more functional using a dictionary. It works fine unless randomNumber doesn't meet any of the predicates. Is there a cleaner way of preventing nulls with linq without having to explicitely check for it in the where clause?

```
Dictionary<Predicate<float>, Func<float, float>> _mutateDict = 
    new Dictionary<Predicate<float>, Func<float, float>>();

_mutateDict.Add((float x) => x <= 2, f => { return f *= -1f; });
_mutateDict.Add((float x) => x <= 4, f => { return Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f); });
_mutateDict.Add((float x) => x <= 6, f => { return f *= 2f; });

float weight = 2f;

float result = _mutateDict
[
    _mutateDict
    .Keys
    .Where(m => m(randomNumber) != null) 
    .FirstOrDefault()
](weight);
```

Comment: You've turned a high-performing O(1) hash table lookup into an O(n) list. I don't understand why the `Predicate<float>` is the key instead of just having `float` as the key. I mean, you're basically using your dictionary as a `List<KeyValuePair<Predicate<float>, Func<float, float>>>`. There's no benefit to making it a dictionary.

Comment: Forgive me for sounding confused. Wouldn't using pattern matching be more 'functional' that this solution?

Comment: Add a catch-all predicate at the end? `x => true`, `f => 0`. And indeed, no need for Dictionary, List is a better fit. Dictionary is unoredered collection, and order is important here (plus you don't use dictionary features anyway).

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks for your feedback. I used a predicate instead of a float because I am checking to see if x is within a range, where x <= 2. Not specifically looking up to see it is just 2.  Fair point about making it a List<KeyValuePair>. Thanks.

Comment: The List solution would have a *worst case* complexity of O(n) whereas the LINQ dictionary has an average case complexity of O(n), as you asked it to find *all* entries where the predicate is true, then only use the first one.

Comment: @Evk Thanks, I added a default value that just returns the float you passed

Comment: @itsme86 thanks for the feedback, I ended up dropping the dict and using the list keyvaluepair as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the comments (which are valid) and answering your question:

`m => m(randomNumber) != null` will always be true. The return from your predicate will always be either `true` or `false`, never `null`, which is why when you set `randomNumber = 8` you get back `-2`: `false != null` -> `true` -> `2.0 *= -1` is `-2`.

Secondly, as when you match none of your predicates, your key (the return from `FirstOrDefault()` will be null, and you aren't handling that.

You *either* need to use multiple lines (checking for null) or have a catch-all entry as Evk suggests. Mjwills solution also works, it's called the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Also, if you use the `.First(m => m(randomNumber))` predicate, you can remove the `Where` predicate entirely, reducing the time complexity back to that comparable to an iterated `List<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the ds to be:

    `List<KeyValuePair<Predicate<float>, Func<float, float>>> _mutations; 

   if(_mutations != null && _mutations.Count > 0)
       _mutations.First(m => m.Key(randomNumber)).Key(weight); `       

Using your suggestion I dropped where and have also added a default catch in the list that just returns the float you passed.

I aplogize, I'm new to Linq. In this situation is there an advantage or preference to using First vs FirstOrDefault? I don't necessarily want an explicit error thrown, which is why I went with FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the question of whether the `Dictionary` is the right data structure for this, I would suggest trying:

```
var result = _mutateDict
[
    _mutateDict
    .Keys
    .Where(m => m(randomNumber) != null)
    .FirstOrDefault()
]?.Invoke(weight);
```

`?.Invoke` [means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

> return `null` if the function I am about to invoke is `null`

which seems to fit what you need.

Comment: Its not superfluous, but rather just badly written. BTW, nice catch on the `?`, I forget it exists in C# (not sure when it was added) and am never 100% sure on the syntax.

Comment: You're right that it will always return `true`, but he *doesn't want it to.* Removing the `!= null` part allows his keys to return false and thus not be considered for the second part of the operation, but leading to the problem of "if they are all false, I get a null reference exception".

Comment: @mjwills Great idea with the null conditional operator, but I'm currently limited to 4.0, and I believe that wasn't introduced until 6.0. Apologies, I should have made it more clear outside of the tag.

Comment: @Alexsh Yeah, I was pretty sure it was added post-4.0 myself, but Microsoft doesn't like saying so on its documentation pages.

Comment: Late to the party here, safe navigation operator was indeed added in C# 6.0